# Pip2 error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, pip

I am having .whl file for tensorflow 1.14.0 to be installed on Raspberry Pi 3B board. When I run the following command,

```
 sudo pip2 install tensorflow-1.14.0-cp27-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0 (from tensorflow==1.14.0) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0 (from tensorflow==1.14.0)
```

I tried to do some other hacks like:

```
sudo pip2 install --ignore-installed --upgrade Downloads/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp27-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```

and even this:

```
curl http://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

but the error remains the same.

Does anyone have any idea about this because I ran the same command on another RPI of same model and the command worked.

Comment: Try preinstalling `tensorboard` from PyPI instead of piwheels: `pip2 install tensorboard==1.14.0 --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple`, then retry the `tensorflow` installation.

Comment: Got this error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorboard==1.14.0 (from versions: )

Comment: Can you rerun the command with `-vvv` and attach its output to the question? E.g. `pip2 install tensorboard==1.14.0 --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple -vvv`

Comment: Now, it gives `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mock>=2.0.0` along with this `SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)`

Comment: `tensorboard` doesn't require `mock`, but the fact you can't install packages from PyPI is either a sign of an old Python 2 installation (what does `python2 -V` return?), or cert store issues. You can try `pip2 install tensorboard==1.14.0 --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple -vvv --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org` to turn off cert checks, but if Python is compiled against an old OpenSSL version, this won't help either.